# An issue with calling static methods from one class

Tags: java

I have a class called `Operators` that contains three static methods: `crossover`, `mutate`, `bestOffSpring`. I call these methods in another class such as:

```
List<Cell> offSpring = Operators.crossover(parent1, parent2);           
Cell bestOffSpring = Operators.bestOffSpring(offSpring);
Cell mutatedChild = Operators.mutate(bestOffSpring);
```

The problem that I am facing is when I just call the `crossover` and `bestOffSpring`, their results are produced correctly. However, when I call `mutate` method, the results of the other two are not correct. In other words, the results of the `crossover` and `bestOffSpring` are affected by calling the `mutate` method. I checked the logic of the three methods and I didn't find any mistake.

My question is does calling many static methods from one class affect their results?

Here is the code of the three methods:

```
public class Operators {

    public static List<Cell> crossover(Cell parenta_,Cell parentb_)
    {

        BitSet parenta = parenta_.getChrom();
        BitSet parentb = parentb_.getChrom();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int setLength = parenta.length();
        //System.out.println("<"+setLength+">");
        BitSet child1 = new BitSet(setLength);
        BitSet child2 = new BitSet(setLength);

        //One point splicing
        int slicePoint = rand.nextInt(setLength); //rnd num between 0-70
        System.out.print("<"+slicePoint+">");
        BitSet a = (BitSet)parenta.clone();
        a.clear(slicePoint,setLength);
        BitSet b = (BitSet)parenta.clone();
        b.clear(0,slicePoint);
        BitSet c = (BitSet)parentb.clone();
        c.clear(slicePoint,setLength);
        BitSet d = (BitSet)parentb.clone();
        d.clear(0,slicePoint);

        //Combine start of p1 with end of p2
        child1.or(a);
        child1.or(d);
        //Combine start of p2 with end of p1        
        child2.or(c);
        child2.or(b);

        //Return the children
        //BitSet[] offspring = {child1, child2};

        Cell child1_ = new Cell(child1);
        Cell child2_ = new Cell(child2);

        System.out.print("C1 = " + child1_.printBit());
        System.out.print(", C2 = " + child2_.printBit() + " ");

        List<Cell> offSpring = new ArrayList<>();

        offSpring.add(child1_);
        offSpring.add(child2_);

        return offSpring;
    }

    public static Cell mutate(Cell original_){
        BitSet original = original_.getChrom();

        Double mProb = 0.4;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int m = 0; m < original.length(); m++)
        {
            //Small possibility a bit copied from parent to child is mutated
            if(rand.nextDouble() <= mProb)
                original.flip(m);
        }
        //Return the (possibly) strategy
        Cell mutated = new Cell(original);
        return mutated;
    }

    public static Cell bestOffSpring(List<Cell> offSpring){
        int offSpringFit1 = offSpring.get(0).getFitness();
        int offSpringFit2 = offSpring.get(1).getFitness();

        if (offSpringFit1 > offSpringFit2)
            return offSpring.get(0);
        else
            return offSpring.get(1);
    }
}
```

Here is an example, the correct results of calling crossover and bestOffSpring are:

```
OffSpring are 100111 <4> and 111101 <5>, best is 111101
OffSpring are 101010 <3> and 111101 <5>, best is 111101
OffSpring are 101111 <5> and 110101 <4>, best is 101111
OffSpring are 110111 <5> and 110111 <5>, best is 110111
OffSpring are 101101 <4> and 110111 <5>, best is 110111
OffSpring are 101010 <3> and 111010 <4>, best is 111010
```

When the mutate method is called the results are:

```
OffSpring are 101101 <4> and 100110 <5>, best is 100110
OffSpring are 101010 <3> and 1100 <5>, best is 1100
OffSpring are 100111 <4> and 10101 <5>, best is 10101
OffSpring are 110111 <5> and 111100 <5>, best is 111100
OffSpring are 101100 <5> and 110101 <4>, best is 101100
OffSpring are 11101 <4> and 101010 <3>, best is 11101
```

The difference between the two results is that the two offsprings in the correct results have the right length (in each offspring how many 1's) and the best among them is selected correctly. While the later does not give the right length and then produce the wrong best offspring.

Comment: There's a lot of required information missing.  You need to show us an exact sequence of calls that results in "wrong" output, and then explain very clearly what the output should be and how the actual output is wrong.  We'll also need to see the definition of class `Cell`. Without that at a minimum nobody can really help you.

Comment: If there is no mutable state there is no way for methods to affect each others' results. Without a MCVE we can use to reproduce this, nobody can say much more about it.

Comment: What stands out to me, is that you're modifying to original, and _then_ creating the copy (instead of the other way around): `original.flip(m);` -> `Cell mutated = new Cell(original);`. This would mean that both the original, and the copy are mutated. If that's intended, it doesn't make sense to make a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side effects 
...

```
if(rand.nextDouble() <= mProb)
                original.flip(m);
```

...

One can presume that `original_.getChrom()` returns the directly the underlying BitSet, so you end up flipping the bites of `bestOffSpring` which in turn will affect the fitness function score after you run `mutate()`.
To avoid the side effect just create a copy of the original Bitset

```
Bitset original = new Bitset(original_.getChrom().size());
original.or(original_.getChrom().size())
```

Check the [Defensive programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/defensive-programming) tag